# Android - Should I use a Handler in that situation?

Tags: android

I'm learning Android, and I'm building an activity that will receive users that are using different devices, and I would like to show all these users nicknames together, in a Listview.

So, I was thinking about how could I do that, and had the idea to use a Handler to update my listview every second, and to display the list of users in real time, for all users that are connected to the activity.

I created a Database using Phpmyadmin, and I'm using Json to print all the informations from the database, so I can use Java to get all the data.

My questions are:

Is there any better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Will my App crash?

Does the handlers have a huge effect on the users battery?

Thank you.

Comment: it's not proper way. does your list get data from server ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is another way you can do it. You can look for `RecyclerView` . And `notifyDataSetChanged()` method. Also you can use `notifyItemRemoved()`bla bla ..

In `RecyclerView` you have an adapter and you give list of items to that adapter. When your item list changed , if you notify it to your adapter your recyclerview should change.

Android Recyclerview : [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Also you can follow guides like in this blog : [Creating lists with recyclerview](http://blog.lovelyhq.com/creating-lists-with-recyclerview-in-android/)